# Content Providers method execution

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have used custom `ContentProvider`, but i am confused about its methods execution.

ContentProvider provide following methods

1. insert()
2. update()
3. delete()
4. query()
5. getType()

I have used `LoaderManager` for background execution of query() method.

Now my question is **insert()** or **update()** methods execution is **Sychronous** or **Asynchronous** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the level of a `ContentProvider`, `insert()` and `update()` are synchronous.

At the level of a `ContentResolver` — which you use for communicating with a `ContentProvider` — `insert()` and `update()` are also synchronous.